# Existence of $1$-dimensional subrepresentation of a $5$-dimensional representation of $A_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

**Question:**

Prove the existence of a $1$-dimensional invariant subspace for any $5$-dimensional representation of the group $A_4$.

**Answer:**

We know that if $V_1,\dots,V_k$ is a complete set of non-isomorphic irreducible representations of $A_4$, then $|G|=\sum (\dim V_i)^2$. In our case, $|A_4|=12$, so for this summation we have the following options

$$3^2+1^2+1^2+1^2$$
$$2^2+2^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2$$
$$2^2+1^2+\cdots+1^2$$
$$1^2+\cdots+1^2$$
$$2^2+2^2+2^2.$$

Last two cases are impossible as $A_4$ is not abelian and there has to be a trivial module of dimension $1$. This would imply that for an arbitrary irreducible representation $V_i$ of $A_4$, we have the following two options

$$\dim V_i=1\; \text{or}\; 3$$
$$\dim V_i=1\; \text{or}\; 2.$$

Thus, since we have a representation of dimension $5$, it has to contain an irreducible representation of dimension $1$. Do you see any mistake in my proof? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Looks OK to me. But since $A_4$ trivially has $4$ conjugacy classes it's clear that $1^2+1^2+1^2+3^2$ is the only relevant case.

Comment: But let's be clear: you are talking about $\mathbb{C}$-representations aren't you?

Comment: Thanks! Well the question is given exactly as I wrote above. Since nothing was given, I assumed we are talking about $\mathbb{C}$-representations.

Comment: I think that if it's real representations then we can have $5=3+2$ where the $2$ is the sum of the two nonreal $\mathbb{C}$ 1-d reps. And as for finite characteristic I am not sure.